# De Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{\text{one point}\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

This question is motivated by Exercise 1.7 from *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by Bott & Tu, book I'm working over on my own. The original question in the text concerns the de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with points $P$ and $Q$ deleted. I have tried to simplify it a bit caring only about one point. So I'm trying to:

> Compute in a rigorous way de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one point $P$ deleted and find the closed forms that represent the cohomology classes.

There are two related questions:

[first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043486/de-rham-cohomology-of-mathbbr2-setminus-k-textpoints)

[second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254123/de-rham-cohomology-of-the-plane-with-m-holes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have already solved the exercise in several ways:

- Using singular cohomology and the isomorphism between singular and the de Rham cohomologies.
- Using Stokes and the ideas of Example 24.4 of Loring's book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

However, I want to solve the exercise rigorously using only what is previously covered in the book: the definition of the de Rham cohomology.

Since I have already solve it by other means, I already know the solution, so I am only interested in the ideas and the heuristics of another approach which uses only what I stated above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should add more detail about the definitions given prior to the exercise in the book. People may more easily understand the situation. Anyway I am throwing in some glimpses of ideas to start with. What you will need to do is to prove that $xdy-ydx$ is (probably the only?) 1-form that is exact, but not closed. To do that assume it was d(.), then you will need to integrate it over a circle around the origin to get a contradiction with the stokes theorem.

Comment: You are right @Behnam. I was being stupid thinking that I couldn't use Stokes but of course I can since I am not assuming Stokes on Manifolds, only in the Euclidean space. I will give it other attempt! And regarding the definitions....they were only defined the concepts of differential forms, differential complexes and de Rham cohomology (also with compact supports).

Comment: I think this covers what you need (1 point only removed): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612837/how-to-compute-the-de-rham-cohomology-of-the-punctured-plane-just-by-calculus

Comment: @aytio thanks for the comment! I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what order material is covered in the book you're referencing, but here's a fairly elementary demonstration that $H^1_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\} \cong \mathbb{R}.$  It requires only material covered in a standard American Calc 3 class, together with basic facts about forms.  For ease of writing, I'll write $M$ for $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0\}$.

**Proposition 1**:  For $\eta = P(x,y) dx + Q(x,y) dy$, $\eta$ is closed iff $P_y = Q_x$.  Said another way, $\eta$ is closed iff the integrand you get in Green's theorem vanishes.

Proof:  Well, since $dx\wedge dx = 0$ $d(Pdx) = P_y dy\wedge dx$.  Likewise, $d(Qdy) = Q_x dx\wedge dy$, so $d\eta = (-P_y + Q_x) dx \wedge dy$.  The result follows.

Now comes the technical result.  In some sense, Proposition 2 is proving that $H^1_{dR}(M)$ is at most an $\mathbb{R}$ because there is only one obstruction to being exact:  $\int_C \eta = 0$.

**Proposition 2**  Suppose $\eta = Pdx + Qdy$ is a smooth $1$-form on $M$.  Let $C$ denote the unit circle with center $(0,0)$ traversed counter clockwise.    Assume $\eta$ is closed.  Then $\eta$ is exact iff $\int_C \eta = 0$.

Proof:  Before proving this, the hypothesis that $\int_C \eta = 0$ implies that $\int_{C_R} \eta =0$ for any circle of radius $R$ centered at $(0,0)$.  Indeed, because $\eta$ is closed, $P_y - Q_x = 0$.   Thus, by Green's theorem, we have $\int_C \eta - \int_{C_R} \eta = \iint_X P_y - Q_x dA$ where $X$ is the annulus between $C$ and $C_R$.  Since $\int_C\eta = 0$ and $P_y - Q_x = 0$, $\int_{C_R}\eta = 0$.  With this out of the way, we can now actually prove this proposition.

First, assume $\eta$ is exact:  $\eta = df$ for some smooth function $f$.  We paramaterize $C$ as $(x,y) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ with $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.  Writing $f(x,y) = f(\cos t, \sin t) = g(t)$ for some smooth function $g$, we then compute $$\int_C df = \int_0^{2\pi} d(f(\cos t, \sin t)) = \int_0^{2\pi} dg = \int_0^{2\pi} g'(t) dt = g(t)|_0^{2\pi} = f(\cos t, \sin t)|_0^{2\pi} = 0.$$  Thus, if $\eta = df$, then $\int_C \eta = 0$.

Now, let's prove the converse, so assume that $\int_C \eta = 0$.  We define a function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $df = \eta$ as follows.  For $p\in M$ which is not on the negative $x$-axis, let $L_p$ denote the segment connecting the point $(1,0)$ to $p$ (which stays in $M$.   For $p\in M$ off of the negative $y$-axis, let $B_p$ a line segment connecting $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ followed by a segment connecting $(0,1)$ to $p$.  For $p$ off of the positive $y$-axis, let $D_p$ be the line segment connecting $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ followed by the segment connecting $(0,1)$ to $q$.

For $p\in M$ note that at least 2 out of three of $L_p$, $B_p$, and $D_p$ are defined.  We claim that $\int_{L_p} \eta = \int_{B_p} \eta$ if both are defined.  Specifically, drawing both $L_p$ and $B_p$, it's clear they make a (possible degenerate) triangle which does not contain $(0,0)$.  Applying Green's theorem, togther with Proposition 1 (and recalling that $\eta$ is closed) shows $\int_{L_p} \eta = \int_{B_p} \eta$.  The same proof works for showing $\int_{L_p}\eta = \int_{D_p}\eta$ (again, assuming both are defined).

To see that $\int_{B_p} \eta = \int_{D_p} \eta$ (assuming both are defined), let $R$ be a large enough so that $B_p \cup D_p$ lies inside the circle of radius $R$ centered at $(0,0)$.  Applying Green's theorem to the region between $B_p\cup D_p$ and $C_R$, we deduce that $\int_{B_p} \eta - \int_{D_p}\eta + \int_{C_R} \eta = 0$.  Since, we have already showed $\int_{C_R} = 0$, it follows that $\int_{B_p}\eta = \int_{D_p} \eta$.

Now, let's first prove that $f_x(p) = P(p)$.  For $h$ small, let $S_h$ be the line segment connecting $p$ to $p + (h,0)$.  If $p$ is not along the negative real axis, then the three paths $L_p$, $S_h$, and $L_{p+(h,0)}$ are defined and form a triangle.  Again applying Green's theorem, we see that $ \int_{L_{p+(h,0)}} \eta  -\int_{L_p}\eta  =\int_{S_h} \eta$.  Paramaterizing $S_h$ via $(x,y) = p + (t,0)$, we see $y' = 0$, so \begin{align*} f_x(p) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p+(h,0)) - f(p)}{h}\\ &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_{S_h} \eta}{h}\\ &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_0^h P dx}{h} \\&= P(p),\end{align*} where the last line uses L'Hospital's rule together with the fundamental theorem of calculus.  If, on the other hand, $p$ is along the negative real axis, repeat this proof with $D_p$ and $D_{p + (h,0)}$ replacing $L_p$ and $L_{p+(h,0)}$.

The proof that $f_y(p) = Q(p)$ is almost identical.  In fact, if $p$ is not on the negative real axis, again use $L_p$ and $L_{p+(0,h)}$.  If $p$ is on the negative real axis, to show $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(p+(0,h)) - f(p)}{h} = Q$, use $B_p$ and $B_{p+(0,h)}$, and to show that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(p+(0,h)) - f(p)}{h} = Q$, use $D_p$ and $D_{p+(0,h)}$.$\square$

Now, let $\omega = \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy.$  Computing $P_y$ and $Q_x$ both gives $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$, so they're equal.  Hence, by Proposition 1, $\omega$ is closed.

**Proposition 3:**  The form $\omega$ is not exact.

Proof:  From proposition $2$, it's enough to compute $\int_C \omega$ where $C$ is the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$.  Paramaterizing the circle via $(x,y) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ with $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, we get $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-\sin t}{\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t} (-\sin t) dt + \frac{\cos t}{\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t}(\cos t) dt = \int_0^{2\pi} (\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t)dt = 2\pi$.  Since $2\pi \neq 0$, $\omega$ cannot be exact. $\square$

If follows that $[\omega]\in H^1_{dR}(M)$ is non-zero.

**Proposition 4:**  Suppose $\eta$ is a closed one form.  There is a real number $\lambda$ with the property that $\lambda \omega - \eta$ is exact.  In other words, $[\eta] = \lambda[\omega]$ so $[\omega]$ generates all of $H^1_{dR}(M)$.

Proof:  Let $\lambda = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_C \eta$, where $C$ is the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$.  Then \begin{align*}\int_C \lambda \omega - \eta &= \lambda \int_C \omega - \int_C \eta\\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_C \eta \int_C \omega - \int_C\eta\\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_C \eta 2\pi - \int_C\eta\\ &= 0.\end{align*}  Since $\lambda \omega - \eta$ is obviously closed, Proposition 2 now implies that $\lambda \omega - \eta$ is exact. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

**Fact** Homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic De Rham Cohomology.

As $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash${point} is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ (define retraction as in image below), 
[image]

we have that

$H_{Dr}^n(\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\text{\{point\}})=H_{Dr}^n(S^1)=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R}, n=0,1\\
0, \text{else}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Your are using homotopy invariance of the De Rham Cohomology and the purpose of the Exercise is precisely to solve the question avoiding extra machinery, using just the definition of  De Rham Cohomology. Therefore, I am afraid I can not accept this as "the answer" to the question. Thanks anyway for your contribution.